# How do I allow users to keep their background color?

Tags: php, html, css, background

I am really stuck and I don't know what to do (I'm new to coding). I have created a user login and register form. I have also created buttons that can change the background color and hide the other buttons. My problem is that when one user, for example, changes their background color, it stays there when another user logins in.

E.g. User 1 logs in and changes their background to blue. User 1 logs out and User 2 logs in. User 2 can see that their background is blue (because of User 1) and changes it to green. User 2 logs out and User 1 logs in and now User 1's background is green and not blue.

I can't figure out how to just save it to the user only. I think it saves to the computer because of the `localStorage`. I am not sure. I want to know how to save this to the user so they can access their own data and not other users' (I'm sorry if this is worded badly). I am having the same problem with the hide/show buttons.

I have tried `cookies`, `window.localStorage` etc but it has the same results.

You can go to https://panda-lingo.com/login.php to try it out and here is my code for index.php:

```
    <?php require_once 'controllers/authController.php';
if (isset($_GET['token'])) {
   $token = $_GET['token'];
   verifyUser($token);
}
if (isset($_GET['password-token'])) {
   $passwordToken = $_GET['password-token'];
   resetPassword($passwordToken);
}


if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('location: login.php');
    exit();

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Panda Lingo | Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit-no">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kosugi+Maru&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jua&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
    .form-div {
        margin: 50px auto 50px;
        padding: 25px 15px 10px 15px;
        border: 1px solid #80ced7;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
    }
    </style>
        <script>
        window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
    </script>



    <script>
        if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
            window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body id="body">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 form-div">

        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>    
    <div class="alert <?php echo $_SESSION['alert-class']; ?>"> 
<?php 
echo $_SESSION['message']; 
unset($_SESSION['message']);
unset($_SESSION['alert-class']);
?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<h3>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h3>

<a href="index.php?logout=1" id="logout">logout</a>

<?php if ($_SESSION['verified']): ?>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">I am verified!</button>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<button class="btn" id="nighttime-button">Dark Mode</button>
<button class="btn" id="white-button">White</button>
<button class="btn" id="pink-button">Pink</button>
<button class="btn" id="red-button">Red</button>
<button class="btn" id="orange-button">Orange</button>
<button class="btn" id="yellow-button">Yellow</button>
<button class="btn" id="green-button">Green</button>
<button class="btn" id="blue-button">Blue</button>
<button class="btn" id="purple-button">Purple</button>
<button class="btn" id="brown-button">Brown</button>
<button class="btn" id="grey-button">Grey</button>
<button id="hide-buttons">Hide Buttons</button>
<button id="show-buttons">Show Buttons</button>
</body>
<script id="background-colors">
    const nightMode = document.getElementById('nighttime-button');
    const whiteBtn = document.getElementById('white-button');
    const pinkBtn = document.getElementById('pink-button');
    const redBtn = document.getElementById('red-button');
    const orangeBtn = document.getElementById('orange-button');
    const yellowBtn = document.getElementById('yellow-button');
    const greenBtn = document.getElementById('green-button');
    const blueBtn = document.getElementById('blue-button');
    const purpleBtn = document.getElementById('purple-button');
    const brownBtn = document.getElementById('brown-button');
    const greyBtn = document.getElementById('grey-button');

    const body = document.getElementById('body');

    if (localStorage.changeBackgroundColor)
    {
        $(body).css('background-color', localStorage.changeBackgroundColor);
    }
        if (localStorage.hideButtons)
    {
        $('.btn').css('display', localStorage.hideButtons);
    }
            if (localStorage.showButtons)
    {
        $('.btn').css('display', localStorage.showButtons);
    }
    
    
    $(nightMode).on('click', function() {
        $(body).css("background-color", "#404040");
        localStorage.changeBackgroundColor = '#404040';
    });

    $(whiteBtn).on('click', function() {
        $(body).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
        localStorage.changeBackgroundColor = '#ffffff';
    });

    $(pinkBtn).on('click', function() {
        $(body).css("background-color", "#ffe6ee");
        localStorage.changeBackgroundColor = '#ffe6ee';
    });

    $(redBtn).on('click', function() {
        $(body).css("background-color", "#FF6961");
        localStorage.changeBackgroundColor = '#FF6961';
    });

    $(orangeBtn).on('click', function() {
        $(body).css("background-color", "#FCB772");
        localStorage.changeBackgroundColor = '#FCB772';
    });

    $(yellowBtn).on('click', function() {
        $(body).css("background-color", "#F8E37B");
        localStorage.changeBackgroundColor = '#F8E37B';
    });

    $(greenBtn).on('click', function() {
        $(body).css("background-color", "#BFF47A");
        localStorage.changeBackgroundColor = '#BFF47A';
    });

    $(blueBtn).on('click', function() {
        $(body).css("background-color", "#CFEDFB");
        localStorage.changeBackgroundColor = '#CFEDFB';
    });

    $(purpleBtn).on('click', function() {
        $(body).css("background-color", "#EED0FA");
        localStorage.changeBackgroundColor = '#EED0FA';
    });

    $(brownBtn).on('click', function() {
        $(body).css("background-color", "#D8AF87");
        localStorage.changeBackgroundColor = '#D8AF87';
    });

    $(greyBtn).on('click', function() {
        $(body).css("background-color", "#E8E8E8");
        localStorage.changeBackgroundColor = '#E8E8E8';

    });
    
        $('#hide-buttons').on('click', function() {
        $('.btn').css("display", "none");
        localStorage.hideButtons = 'none';

    });
    
            $('#show-buttons').on('click', function() {
        $('.btn').css("display", "block");
        localStorage.showButtons = 'block';

    });

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an user_background field, when users choose their background, it will be saved to database. And after user login, you can get and set background by user.

Comment: How would I be able to do that? Do I have to add a new database to do so? Thank you for your answer

Comment: Yes, you add new field user_background in table where saving user info. And add logic code in controller for updating and getting data.

Comment: Do you mind showing me how to do that? I'm new at coding and I'm only just getting used to how a database works so I don't know how to implicate it